# Call Stored procedure (which returns two table) in php

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

I am working in a GUI tool development using php. There are STORED PROCEDURES already present in the database. **Those stored procedures cannot be changed.** (other tool dependency).

**My Question:** There is a procedure which **returns two tables**  when called in mysql directly. (maybe *2 select* statement inside it).

How can I use 'mysqli -- php' to display the data from two tables returned?

**NOTE** : Both table returned has same columns(name,id,status) in it

Comment: I guess you are looking for this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.next-result.php

Comment: @k102 I tried it and got the message "There is error in the query"

Comment: so... there is an error in the query :)

Comment: The query is just `$query = "call proc_name";`
I used both `mysqli_multi_query` and `mysqli_query` functions to execute the query

Answer (score 2):

Make use of [mysqli::use_result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.use-result.php)

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "db_name");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") ";
}

$query = "CALL sp_multiple results (?, ?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

if (!$stmt) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $param1, $param2);

$stmt->execute();

/* get first result set */
if ($result1 = $mysqli->use_result()) {
    //fetch data
    $result1->close();
}

/* get second result set */
if ($result2 = $mysqli->use_result()) {
    //fetch data
    $result2->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: thanks @meda. The code worked partially. The code works till

`/* get first result set */
if ($result1 = $mysqli->use_result())`
php identifies the column name. (gives warning if a wrong column name is specified). But then It enters (fetching) loop once and prints nothing

Comment: @Siva.Grahadurai can you show me the actual code and how you fetch , also try to enable error reporting